# How to read the file from hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I have a text file name mr.txt in the hadoop file sytem under /project1 directory. I need to write the python code to read the first line of the text file without downloading mr.txt file into local. But I have trouble to open the mr.txt file from hdfs.
I had tried:

```
open('hdfs:///project1/mr.txt','r')
```

Comment: "Without downloading `mr.txt`"... Well, you have to do that to actually gather the file on some node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get PySpark installed.

```
text = sc.textFile('hdfs:///project1/mr.txt')
first_line = text.first()
```

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007 . It worked

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing in more detail what your software is or where it is run...

You can use a [NFS server](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html) so you can mount the HDFS volume and access to it locally. If this option does not suit your needs, you should use [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html). Finally if you are writting a Spark job, you can access the HDFS as if it were your local FS.