# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs:///data/testdata.json'

Tags: python

> New to python coding, getting following error
>
> I can view that testdata.json' that this location using
>
> hdfs dfs -ls /data/testdata.json'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "testdata.json'", line 6, in 
>      with open('hdfs:///data/testdata.json') as data_file:
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs:///data/testdata.json'
>   python process_sensor_file.py

```
#!/bin/python
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('hdfs:///data/testdata.json', "r") as data_file:
     source_data = json.load(data_file)
print(source_data)

print(json.dumps(source_data, indent=2))

for item in source_data['CityData']:
            Longitude = item['Longitude']
            TimeStamp = item['TimeStamp']
            print(Longitude, TimeStamp)
```

Comment: read this link, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447912/how-to-read-the-file-from-hdfs

Comment: I am having issue with open statement for json file. File "testdata.json'", line 6, in with open('hdfs:///data/testdata.json') as data_file: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an HDFS driver for python to be able to read from HDFS such as `hdfs3`

from the [docs](https://hdfs3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
hdfs = HDFileSystem(host='localhost', port=8020)
with hdfs.open('/data/testdata.json') as f:
    data = f.read(1000000)
```